# Check string array 1 items are present in string array 2 and return bool

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, string-comparison

I have two arrays. I need to compare them as shown below and the result should be `bool`

```
Input : 
Example 1
---------
stringArray1 = "one","five"
stringArray2 = "two","one" ,"three","five"
Result = true

Example 2
---------
stringArray1 = "one","five"
stringArray2 = "two","three" ,"four","five"
Result = false (As "one" is not present in array2)
```

### Code :

```
string[] stringArray1 = getDataTabledFromSP.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .OrderBy(x => x.ColumnName)
    .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
    .ToArray();

string[] stringArray2 = fetchColumnDetailsOfClientById
    .OrderBy(x => x.ColumnName)
    .Select(myLine => myLine.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

Comment: Hint: `stringArray2.Contains(str)`

Comment: `!stringArray1.Except(stringArray2).Any()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try *set* arithmetics:

```
 bool result = !stringArray1.Except(stringArray2).Any();
```

we *subtract* `stringArray2` from `stringArray1` and then check if we have any item (which is an item of `stringArray1` not present in `stringArray2`).

**Edit:** if `stringArray1` and `stringArray2` can have *duplicates* which should be taken into account (e.g. all *three* equal items should be found in `stringArray2`):

```
  bool result = !stringArray1
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .Select(chunk => Tuple.Create(chunk.Key, chunk.Count()))
    .Concat(stringArray2
       .GroupBy(item => item)
       .Select(chunk => Tuple.Create(chunk.Key, -chunk.Count()))
     )
    .GroupBy(item => item.Item1)
    .Select(chunk => chunk.Sum(item => item.Item2))
    .Any(item => item > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

So do you want something that returns `true` when `stringArray2` contains every item in `stringArray1`?
This should do:

```
// Not any string which is not contained in the stringArray2
!stringArray1.Any(s => !stringArray2.Contains(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq `All()` function if you want to check if all elements of one array present in another or `Any()` function like

```
stringArray2.All(x => stringArray1.Contains(x))
```

Comment: Being `O(N * M)` (time complexity) algorithm it can be inefficient in case of long `stringArray1` and `stringArray2` arrays